# Spring Integration: ClientHttpRequestInterceptor intercept() method not called when request is sent

Tags: spring

I have set up a spring-integration application as followed, and want to log the outbound request using ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.
The setup is below.
I sent the Http-get using curl and got result, but the method CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept() never gets called when app is debugged.

I must have missed something in the setup. Thanks for helping.

Configuration:

```
<bean id="customRT" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="hello.CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 

<int:chain...>
    <int:header-enricher....
    <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://example.com/vhosts"
                           rest-template="customRT"
                           http-method="GET"/>
</int:chain>
```

---

```
public class CustomClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements   ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
        throws IOException {
        logger.info("request.getURI().toString());      
        return execution.execute( request, body );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration and code are correct.  I've forgot that there is a cache installed, and that's why the intercept() method never gets called.